# Application crashing when searching for QLineEdit in QFormLayout

Tags: qt, crash, qlineedit, qformlayout

I've experienced a weird crash when trying to find a `QLineEdit` in a `QFormLayout`.

Firstly, I created a `QFormLayout` and set a name for it:

```
QFormLayout *charColLayout = new QFormLayout; charColLayout->setObjectName("charColLayout");
```

Then, I created a `QLineEdit`, modified it a bit and add it in to the layout, and I also give it a name:

```
QLineEdit *delim = new QLineEdit; 
delim->setMaxLength(1);
delim->setMaximumWidth(100); 
delim->setText("/"); 
delim->setObjectName("delEdit");
charColLayout->addRow("Delimiter", delim);
```

Afterward, in a completely **different** function, I re-searched that layout with `findChild()`:

```
QFormLayout *charcoal = secondHoriField->findChild<QFormLayout *>("charColLayout", Qt::FindChildrenRecursively);
```

It should be noted that `secondHoriField` is just a normal `QLayout` which my `QFormLayout` is located in.

Finally, I attempted to find that `QLineEdit`:

```
QLineEdit *delimEdit = charcoal->findChild<QLineEdit*>("delEdit", Qt::FindChildrenRecursively);
if (delimEdit == nullptr) {cerr << "error\n";} //debug
string curDelim = qStrToStr(delimEdit->text());
```

And it surprisingly came down with a crash, and as the output shown, it's because the `delimEdit` is `null`.

```
18:06:10: Starting D:\...\build-cryptog-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\debug\cryptog.exe ...
error
18:06:17: The program has unexpectedly finished.
18:06:17: The process was ended forcefully.
18:06:17: D:\...\build-cryptog-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\debug\cryptog.exe crashed.
```

But when I switched the `findChild()` function for this rather bruteforce-y line:

```
QLineEdit *delimEdit = dynamic_cast<QLineEdit*>(charcoal->itemAt(1)->widget());
cerr << qStrToStr(delimEdit->objectName()) << endl; //debug line
```

The program ran fine, and it showed the same name I set for the `QLineEdit`:

```
18:12:02: Starting D:\...\build-cryptog-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\debug\cryptog.exe ...
delEdit
18:12:11: D:\...\build-cryptog-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\debug\cryptog.exe exited with code 0
```

Why did this happened?

Another note: `qStrToStr()` is a function I implement to convert `QString` to `std::string`, and I have hand-checked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `findChild` is a QObject method the `itemAt` is a QFormLayout method.

- [QObject::findChild](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild)
- [QFormLayout::itemAt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qformlayout.html#itemAt)

With `addRow` you add an item to the QFormLayout. This does not make it a *child* in the context of the QObject.

- [QFormLayout::addRow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qformlayout.html#addRow-2)

The purpose of the QFormLayout is to organize the positioning of QWidgets, it is not meant to serve as a container. Maybe you could check whether the top level QWidget (e.g. QMainWindow) holding the QFormLayout would be a better choice as a parent for the QLineEdit.

Assuming you have some kind of `QMainWindow`:

```cpp
QMainWindow myMainWindow;
// ...
QLineEdit *delim = new QLineEdit(&myMainWindow);
delim->setObjectName("delEdit");
//...
```

In another location:

```cpp
auto delimEdit = myMainWindow.findChild<QLineEdit*>("delEdit");
```

Comment: It returns an error "No matching constructor for initiliation of `QLineEdit`"

Comment: You are right, QLineEdit takes only `QWidget*` as parents, while QFormLayout does not inherit from QWidget. I will edit my answer and remove the wrong advice.

Comment: But i hope I could explain that there is a difference between a parent-child relationship and a layout-item relationship.

Comment: I've added an alternative. maybe this will help you? :)

Comment: It's usable now, thanks for your support!